# How to represent an IPv6 in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, format, int, ipv6

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient way to store an IPv6 in C++?

Basically I need a format that offer as much flexibility as possible, and compatibility with existing libraries. My first thought was to use a simple `std::vector<int>` since that would allow me to access each part of the address easily.

Is that a good solution? Or am I likely to run into troubles later on?

Comment: To answer this best, I think we need to know a) where you're getting the addresses from, and b) how you're planning on using them (or what APIs you'll be passing them to.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979614/comparison-operations-on-ipv6-address-using-c

Comment: It's an odd question as the default representation is commonly regarded as the most efficient.  Detail on why it is not may be more productive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be fine but you might want to do a std::vector<uint8_t>. I would personally use the struct sockaddr_in6 from c.

```
/* IPv6 address */
struct in6_addr
  {
    union
      {
    uint8_t u6_addr8[16];
    uint16_t u6_addr16[8];
    uint32_t u6_addr32[4];
      } in6_u;
#define s6_addr         in6_u.u6_addr8
#define s6_addr16       in6_u.u6_addr16
#define s6_addr32       in6_u.u6_addr32
  };
```

Include this:

```
  #include <netinet/in.h>
```

That way you can just use static intilization of your address and be done with it. Doing repeated push_backs onto the vector would get very cumbersome and make it a lot harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to store an IPv6 address? If so, int is not enough, you need 128 bits for each.

Comment: I believe he was meaning to store each byte as a separate insertion into the vector.

Comment: Then a c struct should be better. Also, raw packet format should be take care of.